# loop through nested object and change property

Tags: javascript, object

```
const mydata = { 
    message: 'Hello Vues!',
    language: {
        en: {show: false, displayname: "English"},
        ja: {show: true, displayname: "Japanese"},
        zh: {show: false, displayname: "Chinese"},
    }
 }
```

I would like to loop through the 'langauge' object, target it's children, and change all their property "show" into false.

The goal is as follow:

```
const mydata = { 
    message: 'Hello Vues!',
    language: {
        en: {show: false, displayname: "English"},
        ja: {show: false, displayname: "Japanese"},
        zh: {show: false, displayname: "Chinese"},
    }
 }
```

I am looking at `Object.entries` and I can sort of extract the 3 keys (which is en, ja and zh).

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(mydata.language)) {
        console.log(key); //----> gets names of keys
        console.log(key.displayname);//----> undefined
  }
```

However I cant seemed to reference them, loop through it's children and change all 3 records of "show" into false.

Am I looking at the wrong command here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just loop over the value of `mydata.language` with the help of [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and make `show` as `false` as:

```
Object.values(mydata.language).forEach((o) => o.show = false);
```

```js
const mydata = {
  message: 'Hello Vues!',
  language: {
    en: { show: false, displayname: 'English' },
    ja: { show: true, displayname: 'Japanese' },
    zh: { show: false, displayname: 'Chinese' },
  },
};

Object.values(mydata.language).forEach((o) => o.show = false);
console.log(mydata);
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output full height. So IGNORE IT */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
mydata.language[key].show = false;
```

Or

```
value.show = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this via the `Object.keys` method which will return an array of a given object's own enumerable property names, followed by the `forEach` method which will execute a provided function once for each array element. In that function you will set the `show` value to false.

```js
const mydata = { 
    message: 'Hello Vues!',
    language: {
        en: {show: false, displayname: "English"},
        ja: {show: true, displayname: "Japanese"},
        zh: {show: false, displayname: "Chinese"},
    }
 }
 
 Object.keys(mydata.language).forEach(x => mydata.language[x].show = false);
 
 console.log(mydata);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.values` to get the inner objects -- you don't really need the keys then:

```js
const mydata = { 
    message: 'Hello Vues!',
    language: {
        en: {show: false, displayname: "English"},
        ja: {show: false, displayname: "Japanese"},
        zh: {show: false, displayname: "Chinese"},
    }
}

for (let obj of Object.values(mydata.language)) {
    obj.show = false;
}

console.log(mydata.language);
```